# Checking ta.crossover of multiple value sources

Tags: loops, if-statement

so i always fall into this problem and can never figure out another way to do it, here is a sample script to show probably an easy fix for someone experienced

if want a ta.crossunder function tu be looped multiple times to compare diferent ID values of my array

i understand i cant use ta.crossover and if inside a loop, values of X and Y can be modified with inputs so i can just write 50 lines of code to cover all possible crosses

PLEASE AND THX!!!

```
for i = 0 to X
    for i2 = 0 to Y
        if ta.crossover(X[i], X[i2])
             crossoversignal := true
```

i understand i cant use ta.crossover and if inside a loop, values of X and Y can be modified with inputs so i can just write 50 lines of code to cover all possible crosses

PLEASE AND THX!!!